# Bypass IAT hook on screen capture

Tags: delphi, api-hook

I recently comes studing about api hook methods and now my main object of study is IAT hook method, this because I have discovered a security application where only this method of hook was applied for prevent against spywares.

Then, bethween several resources present in this security application,there are lock of screen capture that result in a white screen capture usually, this because IAT hook method had overwritten on table the address the address that points for original function, for a "fake function" that contains this code that locks screen capture.

So, I have read much about IAT hook on web, and found two websites where say ways for bypass this hook method are they:

[iC0de.org](http://www.ic0de.org/showthread.php?10009-SNIPPET-IAT-Hooking-Example) in a answer to a IAT hook source code.

and

[MalwareTech](http://www.malwaretech.com/2013/10/ring3-ring0-rootkit-hook-detection-22.html) on piece of text where explains about IAT hook.

The method for bypass that called attenttion for me was where says for use `GetProcAddress` function for get real address of original function.

So, only for didatical pruporse , I want know how can implement `GetProcAdress` for this screen capture function below and finally bypass IAT hook implemented in this security application:

```
procedure Print;
var 
  DCDesk: HDC;
  bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;

  bmp.Height := Screen.Height;
  bmp.Width := Screen.Width;

  DCDesk := GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow);

  BitBlt(bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Screen.Width, Screen.Height, DCDesk, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

  bmp.SaveToFile('ScreenShot' + '.bmp');

  ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow, DCDesk);

  bmp.Free;
end;
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `GetProcAddress` is for getting the address of an exported procedure or function in a DLL or executable. Unless you exported `Print`, it's not going to be of much use. If you already have studied these kinds of hooks, I can't imaging that you've never exported a dll function before.

Comment: @GolezTrol, this function above, stays in a dll that is injected in a determinated process, but security application still is blocking screen captures.

Answer (score 0):

If your "security application" really does use IAT hooking to prevent a screenshot being taken it would presumably be hooking `bitblt` and then only if the desktop DC is being used and/or the full screen area is being copied - otherwise all the normal "legit" uses of `bitblt` would break also. It seems unlikely that they would not have gone through the fairly trivial additional work it would be to also hook `GetProcAddress` to return the hooked version of `bitblt` if you went that route.

In any case, an IAT hook will only prevent/alter functionality called from within the app itself, so using something like the Windows Snipping Tool or `(Alt)PrtScn` would be unaffected by this.

If you suspect that they used IAT hooking and did *not* hook `GetProcAddress` also then it's just a matter of getting a `bitblt` pointer from that and use it instead of the statically imported function pointer.

Comment: this security application is Truster Rapport of IBM :-). So, using HookShark, you can see that he have only IAT hook. For have a notion, Team Viewer software, also is affected with this IAT hook.

Comment: Yes, that's an example of how to use GetProcAddress.

Comment: What is `BitBlt` definition in Delphi? I'm needing for put on pratice this idea using `GetProcAddress` :-). Or you also could edit your answer with a example of code (using `GetProcAddress` for `BitBlt` as you said) based on code above that I left

Comment: As with most other WINAPI functions, BitBlt is defined in Windows.pas.